# Android: Listen socket all the time

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I have Android application which should connect to the socket server, and all the time listen when new data comes and also have a possibility to send data. For example simple chat. And here I have a few questions:

1) What is the best approach to listen socket all the time ?
   For sure I have to create a separate Thread for that.
   And in this thread I will have something like that i believe:

```
   while (true) {
    // check whether socket input stream has new data
   }
```

Is  that a normal case or there is better solutions ?

2) If while(true) is ok solution, and background thread will work all the time, will it affect UI thread performance ?

3) If while(true) is ok solution, and background thread will work all the time, how seriously it will affect battery life ?

4) Is there any ready solutions, third party libs with callback when new data arrived and so on ?

5) If while(true) bad solution, how people build chat for example ?

Comment: Reading a socket input stream blocks until data or end of stream arrives.

Comment: well. waiting for new data with a connected socket in your own always-running service doesnt seem like the best option. for a chat application, you might want to consider using push messages instead. for example google cloud messaging: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html